# Trying to implement a function that removes all occurrences of a value from a linked list in python

Tags: python, linked-list

```
class LN:
    def __init__(self,value,next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next  = next

def remove(ll,v):
    head = ll
    if head.value == v:
        head = head.next 

    while ll.next.next != None:
        if ll.next.value == v:
            ll.next = ll.next.next
        ll = ll.next
    return head
```

For some reason this function removes only some of the values v but not all of them, how can I modify it so that it removes all occurrences of v?

Thank you !

Comment: Could you post an example of where the values are being skipped. Input list, value to delete and final list. This might make it easier to trace the bug. Try inputs where every value is `value` and every alternate value is `value`.

Comment: `return front` should be `return head`?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's couple of issues with the existing code. When processing the beginning of the list you have to handle the case where there are more than one item at the beginning of the list that needs to be removed. So instead of `if` you need a loop and once you're done with it you can return if all items have been removed

```
while ll and ll.value == v:
    ll = ll.next

# Return if list is depleted or was empty to begin with
if not ll:
    return ll
```

At this point you've either returned or `ll` points to the first node that should be kept, the head of the new list. Since we need to return the head we have to store it and then process all the following nodes. That can be done by checking the value of next node. If it's `v` then it can be skipped over:

```
# At this point ll points to head of the new list
head = ll
while ll.next:
    if ll.next.value == v:
        ll.next = ll.next.next
    else:
        ll = ll.next

return head
```